# Vuejs how to split v-progress linear as 4 piece or are there any option for this design? Vuetify 2

Tags: css, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, progress-bar

I have a table in Vuetify 2; I use v-progress-linear to check how much time the user has left. The first implementation I made was like this.

[image]

But here we decided to divide it into 4 parts to better show the user's time. When I do this; if 4 and less than 4 i will do some coloring. If it is greater than 4, I will show it as one color. Should I use another package for this design? How can I do that? I would be glad if you help.

[image]

My current implementation is simply like this, and the data is coming from the store.

```
           <v-progress-linear
              id="remainingTimeOffBar"
              rounded
              color="monochromeGray2"
              background-color="colorYellow"
              :value="60 - item.remainingDuration"
              height="6"
            />
```

I hope I can find a solution on this. As I said I am using v-table and my searches have been fruitless. Can I handle this with css? or with a package.

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify has no options for changing v-progress-linear to match that design, but you can create your own custom component to match the design with not that much CSS.  Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-tom-oc2c1u?file=/src/App.vue) showing how it can be done.

I'm not exactly sure how the progress amount relates to how much of the bar should be filled in/colored, but it should be easily modifiable to fit your needs. In my example I treat each segment of the progress bar as a separate 25% towards completion and style them according to the actual progress passed down as a prop.

```html
<template>
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div v-for="i in 4" :key="i" class="segment" :style="{ background: segmentColor(i) }" />
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    progress: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  methods: {
    segmentColor(i) {
      if (this.progress <= 25) {
        return "rgb(76, 195, 93)"; // green
      } else if (this.progress > 25 && this.progress <= 50) {
        if (i > 1) {
          return "rgb(255, 200, 15)"; // yellow
        }
      } else if (this.progress > 50 && this.progress <= 75) {
        if (i > 2) {
          return "rgb(255, 200, 15)"; // yellow
        }
      } else {
        if (i === 4) {
          return "rgb(245, 130, 67)"; // orange
        }
      }
      return "rgb(217, 217, 217)";
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.progress-container {
  display: flex;
}
.segment {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 0.5rem;
  background: rgb(217, 217, 217);
}
.segment:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
.segment:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.segment:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: No problem! If the question is now answered please consider clicking the checkmark next to this answer to mark it as correct. Thank you!